# change interval dynamically for clicker game

Tags: setinterval, dynamically-generated

So I already have read other questions about this, but I still do not get it.
I am currently learning JS and I am coding a simple clicker game as a project to show to possible employers.

this is my gameData object:

```
let gameData = {
coins: 0,
coinsPerClick: 1,
upgradeClickCost: 10,
coinsPerSecond: 0,
upgradeSecondCost: 50,
intervalTime: 1000,
intervalReduceCost: 20
```

};

this should be my interval reduce upgrade to generate a coin every x ms instead of the current 1000 ms

```
interval_upgrade.addEventListener("click", e => {
  gameData.coins = gameData.coins - gameData.intervalReduceCost;
  gameData.intervalTime -= 50;
  gameData.intervalReduceCost *= 1.5;
  interval_time.innerHTML = `Interval time : ${Math.round(gameData.intervalTime)} ms`;
  interval_upgrade.innerHTML = `Reduce interval time / Cost = ${Math.round(gameData.intervalReduceCost)}`;
  upgrade_control();
  upgrade_control_second();
  upgrade_control_interval();
```

i get that i need to stop the former interval and run the new one with the new value for the interval timing. i just do not know how.